# хочу при нажатии на кнопку, всплывающее окно, но не получается.

Tags: java, android

1. Это мой Java код

   ```
   public class Test extends Activity {

   private Button test;
   private PopupWindow popupWindow;
   private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
   private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

       test = findViewById(R.id.button);
       relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.semed);
       test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)    
   getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

           ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) 
   layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cimi, null);

           popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, 400, 400, true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 
    500, 500);

           container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                       popupWindow.dismiss();
                       return false;
                   }
               });

           }
       });

     }
   }
   ```
2. это xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout

       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/semed"
       tools:context="messenger.hfad.com.ders.Test">

       <Button

      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="187dp"
      android:text="@string/dersinbuttonu"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="221dp" />

     </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. это созданный layout cimi

   ```
   <RelativeLayout

     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <TextView

      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="216dp"
      android:text="@string/dersintexti" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: что именно происходит не так, как вы хотели?

Comment: я кликаю по кнопке и ничего не происходит